# Higher than maxNativeZoom requests tiles

Tags: leaflet, tiles, zoom, esri-leaflet

Leafet is requesting tiles while at a higher zoom level than maxNativeZoom from defined mapserver instead of just stretching the maxzoom sized tiles. It is creating a lot of 404s since my maxzoom is 18 and the maxNativeZoom is 13. Is this expected or desired behavior? I would like it to display the level 13 tiles at level 18.

Leaflet 1.3.1

```
var mylayer = L.esri.dynamicMapLayer({
  url: "https://gis1.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/thelayer/MapServer/",
  useCors: false,
  maxNativeZoom: 13,
  maxZoom: 18,
  f: "image",
  opacity: "0.5"
```

});

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`maxZoom` and `maxNativeZoom` are valid constructor options for `L.esri.tiledMapLayer` because it extends [`L.GridLayer`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#gridlayer-maxnativezoom).

neither are valid for `L.esri.dynamicMapLayer` (because it extends [`L.ImageOverlay`](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.2.html#imageoverlay-option)).

layer types in Esri Leaflet: http://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/tutorials/introduction-to-layer-types.html